# How to move column value into newly created column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT QueryRun, Count(*) as TotalN, Avg(MDays) as AvgMDays
FROM table_name 
WHERE YN = 1 AND HF = 0
GROUP BY QueryRun
ORDER BY QueryRun DESC;
```

That returns the following output:

```
QueryRun      TotalN        AvgMDays
4/4/23        100           10
3/30/23       115           7
3/23/23       90            8
3/16/23       85            6
3/9/23        105           11
3/2/23        95            12
```

I want to edit my query above so it returns the following:

```
TotalN       Trailing4WkTotalN        AvgMDays         Trailing4WkAvgMDays
100          105                      10               11
```

I want to return one record: the TotalN value for the current date, TotalN value from 4 weeks ago (in this case 3/9/23), AvgMDays for the current date, and AvgMDays from 4 weeks ago. I've tried using LEAD but it didn't work.

How can I get this output?

Comment: Which database are you using? My first instinct here is a lateral JOIN, but the syntax is different (or not even an option) depending on what database you have. You might also join to a row_number() projection from the same table ON rn = 1.

Comment: Hello @JoelCoehoorn, I'm using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Probably you can use your existing query with a specific date criteria and a cross apply of the same logic using a datediff correlation - basically the lateral join as suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct is to use an APPLY lateral join. It should work, though I doubt this is the most efficient way:

```
WITH grouped AS (
   SELECT QueryRun, Count(*) as TotalN, Avg(MDays) as AvgMDays
   FROM table_name 
   WHERE YN = 1 AND HF = 0
   GROUP BY QueryRun
)
SELECT TOP 1 g.QueryRun, g.TotalN, t.TotalN AS Trailing4WkTotalN, g.AvgMDays, t.AvgMDays As Trailing4WkAvgMDays
FROM grouped g
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 TotalN, AvgMDays
    FROM grouped g0 
    WHERE g0.QueryRun <= DATEADD(week, -4, t.QueryRun)
    ORDER BY g0.QueryRun DESC
) t -- t is for "trailing"
ORDER BY g.QueryRun DESC
```

I do expect you can get more efficient if you can **KNOW**, with absolute certainty, there is always a record for the day that is **EXACTLY** 4 weeks in the past:

```
WITH cur AS (
   SELECT TOP 1 QueryRun FROM table_Name ORDER BY QueryRun DESC
)
SELECT t.QueryRun, COUNT(*) AS TotalN, MAX(t0.TotalN) As Trailing4WkTotalN
    Avg(MDays) As AvgMDays, MAX(t0.AvgMDays) As Trailing4WkAvgMDays
FROM table_name t
INNER JOIN cur ON cur.QueryRun = t.QueryRun
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT COUNT(*) As TotalN, Avg(MDays) As AvgMDays
    FROM table_name t0
    WHERE t0.QueryRun = DATEADD(week, -4, t.QueryRun)
) t0
GROUP BY t.QueryRun
```

Just keep in mind: any possibility of the dates not being exactly 4 weeks apart breaks this.

Answer (score 1):

```
with data as (
    SELECT QueryRun, Count(*) as TotalN, Avg(MDays) as AvgMDays,
        lead(Count(*), 4) over (order by QueryRun desc) as Trailing4WkTotalDays,
        lead(Avg(MDays), 4) over (order by QueryRun desc) as Trailing4WkAvgMDays,
        row_number() over (order by QueryRun desc) as rn
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE YN = 1 AND HF = 0
        -- possible optimization
        and QueryRun >= datediff(week, -5, getdate())
    GROUP BY QueryRun
)
select * from data where rn = 1;
```

Does also assume no gaps in data.

```
with data as (
    SELECT QueryRun, Count(*) as TotalN, Avg(MDays) as AvgMDays,
        max(QueryRun) over () as maxQR
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE YN = 1 AND HF = 0
    GROUP BY QueryRun
)
select
    maxQR as QueryRun,
    min(case when QueryRun = maxQR then TotalN end) as TotalN,
    min(case when QueryRun = maxQR then AvgMDays end) as AvgMDays,
    min(case when QueryRun = dateadd(week, -4, maxQR) then TotalN end) as Trailing4WkTotalDays,
    min(case when QueryRun = dateadd(week, -4, maxQR) then AvgMDays end) as Trailing4WkAvgMDays
from data;
```

This one makes no assumptions about how many weeks are present.